# Parse JSON array in Typescript

Tags: json, typescript, ionic2

i have a JSON response from remote server in this way:

```
{
  "string": [
    {
      "id": 223,
      "name": "String",
      "sug": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "jId": 530,
      "pcs": [{
        "id": 24723,
        "name": "String",
        "sug": "string"
      }]
    }, {
      "id": 247944,
      "name": "String",
      "sug": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "jlId": 531,
      "pcs": [{
        "id": 24744,
        "name": "String",
        "sug": "string"
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

In order to parse the response, to list out the "name" & "description", i have written this code out:

```
interface MyObj {
  name: string
  desc: string
}
let obj: MyObj = JSON.parse(data.toString());
```

My question is how do i obtain the name and description into a list that can be displayed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You gave incorrect type to your parsed data. Should be something like this:

```
interface MyObj {
  name: string
  description: string
}

let obj: { string: MyObj[] } = JSON.parse(data.toString());
```

So it's not `MyObj`, it's object with property `string` containing array of `MyObj`. Than you can access this data like this:

```
console.log(obj.string[0].name, obj.string[0].description);
```

Instead of using anonymous type, you can also define `interface` for it:

```
interface MyRootObj {
  string: MyObj[];
}

let obj: MyRootObj = JSON.parse(data.toString());
```

Comment: One additional remark to the already good answer: There is no guarantee that the `JSON.parse`d data realy conforms to the interface that was defined after parsing. If the server suddenly sends other data it might no longer conform to it, and accessing the data through the previously expected interface might lead to a crash. So it's always recommended to validate the data between parsing and using it.

Comment: It is indeed an excellent answer, however, were i to insert into the HTML, please how would go about. I used `*ngFor = "let obj of foundData"` but cannot seem to get the list of name

Comment: Oh and @Matthias247, how do i validate the data please?

Comment: @JendorskiLabs `<p *ngFor = "let item of obj.string">{{ item.name }}</p>`

Comment: Thanks, i tried that already. error from JavaScript Console reads `Cannot read property 'string' of undefined`. I also tried `<p *ngFor = "let item of obj">{{ item.string[0].name }}</p>` to no avail.

Comment: from the console message, only the first set of name and description is displayed, i am looking to list all the `name` and `description` via `html` using `ngFor`. Will using interface help solve this?

Comment: @JendorskiLabs If it works in console and you exposed same `obj` variable to your template, code from my previous comment should give you what you want.

Comment: @JendorskiLabs You can also try to use elvis operator: `<p *ngFor = "let item of obj?.string">{{ item.name }}</p>`. That should help if `obj` is initially undefined.

Comment: Please what do i do, i have next to no knowledge in Typescript, but for SO. Using Yaroslav Admin recommendation to use `<p *ngFor = "let item of obj.string">{{ item.name }}</p>`, an error in the Javascript console is displayed, even, the page does not load

Comment: @JendorskiLabs note "?." In my previous comment.

Comment: Sure, i did notice it, i am using the ionic 2 framework, could that be a problem?, as the latest recommendation did not display the list.

Comment: Any reason not to use `let objs: Array<myObj> = JSON.parse(data.toString());` ?  Works for me and smells a bit more elegant.